# Entire function with conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $h: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ learns such that $h(0) = 0, h^{\prime}(0) = 1$  and $\left|h^{\prime}(z)\right| \leq 1$ if $\left|z\right| \leq 5$. Determine the function $h$.

I set $g(z) = h^{\prime}(z) -1$ which is whole and fulfilled that $g(0) = 0$, the other hypothesis not expect any suggestions how to use it.

Comment: It would help if you fixed your notation. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: Perhaps the Schwartz Lemma might help here.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan How do you turn it into something you can apply Scwarz to? You can't biholomorphically transform the problem to the disc, of course, by Louiville. Do you mind giving a hint? :)

Answer (score 1):

Strong maximum principle: the modulus of a holomorphic function does not have interior maxima, unless the function is constant.

By assumption, $|h'|$ has an interior maximum in the domain $\{z:|z|<5\}$. Hence, $h'$ is constant. The form of $h$ is easy to determine from here.